# Outlook PowerShell script to set Direct Replies To address

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, powershell-4.0, office-automation

I have an automated powershell script to send alert email. Since the alert are send from a generic email.. i want people replying to the email to goto another email address say efg@outlook.com.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "asd@outlook.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Alert Email"
$Mail.HtmlBody = $HTML
$Mail.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", "<efg@outlook.com>")
$Mail.display()
$Mail.send()
```

somehow this is not working.

Managed to get it from the below
[ReplyRecipientNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyrecipientnames)

```
$Mail.ReplyRecipientNames = "efg@outlook.com"
```

Comment: Then why not set that address in the `.From` property?

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. The mail is send from a generic mailbox say 123@outlook.com. And when they reply to the email.. i want the reply to hit the mailbox efg@outlook.com

Comment: On exchange server you can set up a redirect rule to have incoming mail to someone be sent to another email account. If you're using Outlook Web App you can set up such a rule yourself see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-rules-to-automatically-forward-messages-45aa9664-4911-4f96-9663-ece42816d746)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which allows setting up an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. Be aware, the account should be configured in Outlook in that case. For example, here is a VBA code sample which shows how to set up the property:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

For Exchange users you may also consider using the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which is represented by a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

But also you may be interested in the [MailItem.ReplyRecipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyrecipients) property which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the reply recipient objects for the Outlook item. The following article which I wrote for the technical blog shows how to deal with a recipient collection, see [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) for more information.

Comment: There is an option in Outlook called Direct Replies To where i can enter a distribution list name and people replying to the email gets the "To" address field auto populate with the DL name. How do i get this working from a script.

Comment: Use the `MailItem.ReplyRecipients` property for that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `MailItem` object does not expose the `Headers` property - your script will stop rigth there.

If you want to redirect replies to a different address, use `Mail.ReplyRecipients.Add("efg@outlook.com")`